# C - Refactoring multiple OR in an if statement conditional

Tags: c, if-statement, refactoring

In an example like this, is there a nicer/better way to refactor all of the conditionals?

```
if (memberStatus == bronze || memberStatus == silver || memberStatus == gold) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: `return (memberStatus == bronze || memberStatus == silver || memberStatus == gold);`

Comment: Normally you'd use `switch`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This isn't nicer now, is it? it's just a little shorter...

Comment: @machine_1 Taste question I guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way of breaking this out:

```
switch (memberStatus) {
  case bronze:
  case silver:
  case gold:
    // Your code here.
    break; // Don't forget this or it'll "chain through" into the next section
  default:
    // If none of those matched.
}
```

In your case if you're just forcing a `return 1` then the `break` isn't necessary, you can just return. `switch` will chain into the next section unless it's explicitly halted with `break` or `return`.

Comment: This is it! thank you so much - It's amazing how obvious something is once you look at it.

Comment: If this solved your problem mark it as the accepted answer. This helps steer others in a similar situation towards solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
return memberStatus == bronze || memberStatus == silver || memberStatus == gold;
```

is the obvious way.

Although if you have something like

```
int metal = bronze | silver | gold;
```

with `bronze`, `silver`, and `gold` having mutually exclusive 1 bits once any numeric conversions have taken place (along with any other possibility), then you could write

```
return memberStatus & metal;
```

In reality, `metal` would be part of an `enum` also containing the other values; I'm using `int` here to allow the compiler to give me an adequate type which might not be the the case if the above is a narrowing comversion; to emphasise you’d  hope that `bronze`, `silver`, and `gold` are part of the same `enum`, or have the same type if not.

Comment: For non-obvious ways something like `return memberStatus <= gold;` could work in case these are consecutive `enum` members.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Very true and possibly a better way than I have it.

Comment: `<=` might be fragile. Maybe later someone adds copper and then that gets caught up in the `<=` where it shouldn't. And for mutually exclusive bits I usually make an enum for the bit number (used for shifts) and generate the values form those (used to mask bits).

Comment: With compiler FLAGs turned ON this `auto metal` will not compile because the type defaults to 'int'. You need need explicit `auto int metal` or just `int metal` here

Comment: @Michi: You can't assume `int` either. A bit more typing has made the answer a little more rigorous.

Comment: @Bathsheba You right. The type I used was `int`. But you understand my Point. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba I think `return memberStatus & ( bronze | silver | gold );` is shorter.

Comment: @Michi: But flakier than a masking approach.

Comment: This has potential hazards. Imagine if `bronze` is a `char` and `silver` and `gold` is `int`. Not likely, but it could be the case.

Comment: @klutt: No, so long as the 1 bits are mutually exclusive, it's fine.

Comment: Actually @klutt has a point, if `char` and `int` have different complementing schemes. Another tweak. But the answer is getting harder to understand now ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, but I thought you already explained that `or have the same type if not.`

Comment: @Michi: Another edit. Note decltype is compile time evaluable so there's no overflow hazard.

Comment: @Bathsheba Any way this will work fine for `bronze | silver | gold` being `0` or `1`. If silver (or one of them) has `3` then this =>> `return memberStatus & ( bronze | silver | gold );` will return `1` when probably only for `0` and `1` is needed.

Comment: One more thing, isn't `decltype` C++ only?

Comment: @klutt Yes it is, but here I think he meant that the type should be the same as `bronze | silver | gold`

Comment: Oops. I had my C++ hat on.